# Route 53 Routing Polices and IOS Apps

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, geolocation, amazon-route53

I have an ios app that networks with an aws elastic beanstalk environment in the US East (N. Virginia) region. I am in the process of replicating the aws elastic beanstalk environment in the US West (N. California) region. The end goal is to have two multiregional-active-active elastic beanstalk environments.

I am currently using a geolocation identifying service within the ios app in order to gauge the general locations of users to help me decide when to build out an active-active architecture. If a user is on WiFi, I can locate the users region. However, I cannot locate the users region if they are using cell service.

Can the Route 53 geolocation routing policies route the http networking traffic coming from within ios apps that is not on WiFi?

And/Or

Can the Route 53 latency routing policies route the http networking traffic coming from within ios apps that is not WiFi?